# Integrating pods with all targets

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podfile, xcode-project

I have been using CocoaPods for a few weeks now with my iOS app and it works perfectly with the one target I have been testing (let's call it "MainApp"). However, I now want to build a different target ("MyAppLite") and noticed that the build failed (file not found on one of the pods' header files).

The differences in the Build Settings I've noticed are as follows:

- Other Linker Flags does not contain the required frameworks in MyAppLite
- Framework/Header/Library Search Paths are all empty in MyAppLite
- None of the User-Defined Build Settings in MainApp are present in MyAppLite

How can I ensure that when I run `pod install`, all targets have the libraries linked?

For reference, here is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '5.0'

pod 'TTTAttributedLabel', '~> 1.7.0'
pod 'iRate', '~> 1.7.5'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.6'
pod 'FlurrySDK', '~> 4.2.3'
pod 'ACSimpleKeychain', '~> 0.0.1'
pod 'WEPopover', '~> 0.0.1'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.3.1'
pod 'Nimbus', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'QuincyKit', '~> 2.1.9'
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For CocoaPods 1.0.0, recommendation from devs is using `abstract_target` (but not compatible with 0.39.0):

```
platform :ios, '5.0'

abstract_target 'defaults' do
    pod 'TTTAttributedLabel', '~> 1.7.0'
    pod 'iRate', '~> 1.7.5'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.6'
    pod 'FlurrySDK', '~> 4.2.3'
    pod 'ACSimpleKeychain', '~> 0.0.1'
    pod 'WEPopover', '~> 0.0.1'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.3.1'
    pod 'Nimbus', '~> 1.0.0'
    pod 'QuincyKit', '~> 2.1.9'

    target 'MyApp'
    target 'MyAppLite'
end
```

For CocoaPods 0.39.0 + 1.0.0 compatibility, using `def` works fine (but isn't recommended by devs):

```
platform :ios, '5.0'

def default_pods
    pod 'TTTAttributedLabel', '~> 1.7.0'
    pod 'iRate', '~> 1.7.5'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.6'
    pod 'FlurrySDK', '~> 4.2.3'
    pod 'ACSimpleKeychain', '~> 0.0.1'
    pod 'WEPopover', '~> 0.0.1'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.3.1'
    pod 'Nimbus', '~> 1.0.0'
    pod 'QuincyKit', '~> 2.1.9'
end

target 'MyApp' do
    default_pods
end

target 'MyAppLite' do
    default_pods
end
```

Answer (score 21):

## With CocoaPods 1.x

You can use the `target` blocks

```
platform :ios, '13.0'


def default_pods
    pod 'TTTAttributedLabel', '~> 1.7.0'
    pod 'iRate', '~> 1.7.5'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.6'
    pod 'FlurrySDK', '~> 4.2.3'
    pod 'ACSimpleKeychain', '~> 0.0.1'
    pod 'WEPopover', '~> 0.0.1'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.3.1'
    pod 'Nimbus', '~> 1.0.0'
    pod 'QuincyKit', '~> 2.1.9'
end

target 'MyApp' do
  default_pods
end

target 'MyAppLite' do
  default_pods
end
```

Relevant [documentation](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html)

Comment: This is essentially what I did, but I had to define an explicit target containing all pods, followed by the line `link_with ['MyApp', 'MyAppLite']` before the list of pods.

Comment: Can I ask why you had to do so?

Comment: Yeah, probably an unrelated typo or something. It works great now.

Comment: note with version 1.2.0, this no longer works. [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] The specification of `link_with` in the Podfile is now unsupported, please use target blocks instead..

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50874730/6108739) works for me

Answer (score 9):

If you have large number of targets and don't want to add new target each time, you can use this

```
def common_pods

   pod 'TTTAttributedLabel', '~> 1.7.0'
   pod 'iRate', '~> 1.7.5'
   pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.6'
   pod 'FlurrySDK', '~> 4.2.3'
   pod 'ACSimpleKeychain', '~> 0.0.1'
   pod 'WEPopover', '~> 0.0.1'
   pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.3.1'
   pod 'Nimbus', '~> 1.0.0'
   pod 'QuincyKit', '~> 2.1.9'

end

project = Xcodeproj::Project.open “./<projectNameHere>.xcodeproj"

project.targets.each do |t|

target t.name do

    common_pods

end
```

Comment: Hi, it's not working. It's giving error: `[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting end.`

Answer (score 3):

From the docs:

*If no explicit target is specified, then the Pods target will be linked with the first target in your project.*

You can use [link_with](http://docs.cocoapods.org/podfile.html#link_with) to link with further targets.

Also see [Multiple Targets](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/A-Podfile#multiple-targets) in the Cocoapods documentation if you need different dependency configurations for different targets

Comment: Build Settings are set automatically with `pod install` - I don't want to start manually messing with things that should be correctly automatically generated - isn't that the whole point of CocoaPods?

Comment: Also, I want to set exactly the same dependencies for all targets.