# Library search paths get removed when updating pod dependencies

Tags: ios, xcode

After trying to add `Firebase` to my project through pod install I got some weird linker error and if I am right is caused because the field in Build `Settings/Library` Search Paths is empty.

Before running `pod install`, that field wasn't empty. Another thing I noticed is that, that field is not empty for one of my targets and if I switch to that target the project builds properly without errors.

I double clicked on the working target Library Search Paths field to copy it and it says:  **"$(inherited)"**. When I paste it to the other target, nothing changes.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by following the solution on this thread:

[Integrating pods with all targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507711/integrating-pods-with-all-targets?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)